# camera calibration problem - computer vision

Tags: computer-vision, robotics

I am new to computer vision and I have a problem which may not require a complex algorithm, however im not sure if I have enough data to ignore this.

problem statement:
I have a 6-joint robot arm and a 3D camera with trackers. With these trackers I can obtain the homogenous transformation matrix anywhere in the camera coordinate system. I can also obtain the transformation matrix from robot base to end effector. By putting a marker at the end of the end-effector we can get the same 3D coordinate in the camera frame which corresponds to the same point in the robot coordinate system. (We can obtain a set with 3D points if necessary).
Is it possible to find the position and/or orientation of the camera with respect to the robot coordinate system with the given info? Or should i consider the pinhole camera model and perform a least square estimation(SVD, 8-point algorithm)?

[robot coordinate system and camera coordinate system in world frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaPuj.jpg)